# Standard headers not found when switching to clang 3.4 and libc++

Tags: c++, build, cmake, clang, standard-library

I'm getting the following error on CircleCI after installing clang 3.4 and switching to libc++ . . .

> ```
> gtest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:54:10: fatal error: 
>       'limits' file not found
> #include <limits>
> ```

The offending header file is located at `/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.4/include/`, but I cannot prevent the error, even when using the CMake `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM path_above)` or setting the `isystem` compiler flag.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing the issue once. This happened for me because I because was building clang from the source and had multiple instances of the binary. If memory serves, I solved it by setting the `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` flags in the `~/.bashrc` file.

You can do that by adding the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file like this:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.4/include/
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.4/include/
```

Once you have done this, you can either open a new terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` (so that it reads the updated `~/.bashrc` file)